# Postgresql trigger function that checks if data that's been updated in a single column is equal to something

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have a single table `A` with 3 columns `id`, `name`, `price`.
I'm trying to create a trigger in postgres that fires when the value under `price` is updated/set to 0.
If the value is 0, then the entire row is deleted.

I'm a complete beginner in postgresql but I desperately need this for my node.js project.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward.

The first step is to create the trigger logic.  This example deletes the row from `a` if `price = 0`.  The `id = NEW.id` restricts this deletion to the row that just changed.

```
create or replace function zero_price_delete() 
returns trigger language plpgsql 
as $$
begin
  delete from a where price = 0 and id = NEW.id; 
  return new;
end; $$;
```

Then assign this as an `after` trigger on `A` following `insert` or `update` operations.

```
create trigger zero_delete 
 after update or insert on a 
 for each row 
 execute procedure zero_price_delete();
```

Comment: This is perfect but one question; what would I do if the primary key in the row that I want to delete is a composite key of 2 columns?

Comment: @TorrinoMcQueen You can reference both (or all if more) of the columns using the `NEW` row.  e.g. `where price = 0 and id1 = NEW.id1 and id2 = NEW.id2`